# LARAVEL 9: I cannot reach my css file code anytime i have a doube url like this : /user/profile. How can i solve this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

LARAVEL 9: I am using a template in Laravel 9 and I cannot reach my CSS file code anytime I have a double URL like this : /user/profile. However, It only works when I have a single URL like this: /profile. But I want to be able to reach my CSS files when I have double URLs. How can I solve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the path of your CSS file in your template, do you use relative or absolute ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load css and js file in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738220/how-to-load-css-and-js-file-in-laravel)

Comment: I don't think that is called "double URL". The most probable cause is your css not being where you are telling your template the css is.

Comment: Without extra information, we cannot help you. What is your directories/files tree? What is the directory in which the template is? Where is the css? What are the lines where you indicate to the template where to find the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put the files correctly in the public folder?
Do you invoke it correctly within the blade as the following example:

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Have you checked the error by inspecting your browser?

You can check this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-link-external-css-file-to-laravel-blade-file) contains many useful examples for your case

Answer (score 0):

Put a slash "/" at the beginning of the css address. For example if you have somethin like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Change it to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```